# Python: mplot3d, graphing a solid

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, mplot3d

I'm trying to graph a wireframe solid of revolution. I'm following the example for a sphere [here](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/plot_directive/mpl_examples/mplot3d/surface3d_demo2.py) but I'm a bit at a loss. I've simplified everything down, but am now stuck on an error. I'm also looking at the function arguments described [here](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html), but unless I'm misunderstanding something, this code should be okay. I do realize that what I'm trying to draw here is a line and not a shape, but I don't understand why I can't use this method to draw it anyway. I'm trying to get this example as simple as possible so I can move on to graphing an actual solid. Here it is:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
import numpy
import pylab

fig = plot.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

n = numpy.linspace(0, 100)

x = n
y = x**2
z = 1
ax.plot_wireframe(x, y, z)

plot.show()
```

Here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    ax.plot_wireframe(x, y, z)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py", line 687, in plot_wireframe
    rows, cols = Z.shape
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When matplotlib writes data arguments in capital letters, that means it's expecting matrices of data. You can use the `meshgrid` function (see the [example for `mplot3d`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.Axes3D.plot_surface)) to generate the grid.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
import numpy
import pylab

fig = plot.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

n = numpy.linspace(0, 100)

x = n
y = x**2

X, Y = numpy.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = numpy.ones_like( X )

ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z)
```

Note that in the example you gave, the mesh points for the sphere are constructed using an [outer product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product).